# Binary Search Tree delete function wiping the entire tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a BST class but the delete method seems to be incorrect (or perhaps one of its supporting methods) as calling it on any element causes the root to become null. Can someone please help figure out where the issue is?

```
public void delete(DynamicSetBST T, Node z) {
    if(z.left == null) {
        transplant(T, z, z.right);
    }else if(z.right == null) {
        transplant(T, z, z.left);
    }else {
        Node y = successor(z.right);
        if(!y.p.equals(z)) {
            transplant(T, y, y.right);
            y.right = z.right;
            y.right.p = y;
        }
        transplant(T, z, y);
        y.left = z.left;
        y.left.p = y;
    }
}

public void transplant(DynamicSetBST T, Node u, Node v) {
    if(u.p == null) {
        T.root = v;
    }else if(u.equals(u.p.left)) {
        u.p.left = v;
    }else {
        u.p.right = v;
    }
    if(v != null) {
        v.p = u.p;
    }
}

public Node successor(Node x) {
    if(x.right != null) {
        return min(x.right);
    }
    Node y = x.p;
    while(y != null && x.equals(y.right)) {
        x = y;
        y = y.p;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to adjust the successor method. My instructions for the assignment are a bit confusing and its unclear if its supposed to set Node y as the minimum of z or what. Also tried if maybe return; statement are necessary in successor. Nothing works, I still end up with a root that is null.

Comment: I would highly recommend you change the code to use meaningful parameter and local variable names. Might be easier to see the bug that way. Would definitely be easier to read the code, that's for sure.

Comment: Nvm figured it out. Thanks anyway